# Custom Charm in Metro Style Apps

Tags: microsoft-metro

How to implement Custom Charm in Windows 8 Metro Style Application.Please help me.

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com ?  Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) on this site to learn how to ask a good question.  Hint: this is not it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Charms are defined by Windows. So, there is no way for an app to add custom ones.

An application should use its app bar (top or bottom) to provide commands. For more details, read [Guidelines and checklist for app bars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465302.aspx).